# Is there Vespa distribution for Debian machines?

Tags: vespa

Current Vespa distribution, rpm, works on RedHat linux. Is there any easy way to setup multi node vespa cluster on Debian Linux machines?

Answer (score 3):

As of today, you must build Vespa as described in http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/build-vespa.html on Debian - then follow http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/multinode-systems.html.

I do not know of any blockers on Debian, curious to learn, please share your experiences and make PRs for documentation/Vespa improvements :-)